# Unable to upload files in Laravel 8

Tags: php, html, file-upload, laravel-8

I'm unable to upload any files through form. Storage is linked.

HTML:

```
        <form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="{{ route('home.profile.photo.update') }}" method="post">
            @csrf
            @method('PUT')
            <input type="file" name="image" id="image">
            <input type="submit">
        </form>
```

PHP.ini:

```
[PHP]
post_max_size = 100M
upload_max_filesize = 100M
variables_order = EGPCS
```

Route:

```
Route::put('/home/profile/photo', [App\Http\Controllers\HomeController::class, 'updateProfileImage'])->name('home.profile.photo.update');
```

HomeController updateProfileImage():

```
public function updateProfileImage(Request $request){
    dd($request->input());
    $request->validate(
        [
            'image' => 'required',
        ]
    );
    $result = Auth::user()->addMedia($request->input('image'))->toMediaCollection('user-images');
    return $result;
}
```

DD output

```
array:2 [▼
  "_token" => "nLJx2jVbBCfCJUAsIPS7LJGVv7Rpcb72yPXqMO7v"
  "_method" => "PUT"
]
```

Using enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded" DD output:

```
array:3 [▼
  "_token" => "nLJx2jVbBCfCJUAsIPS7LJGVv7Rpcb72yPXqMO7v"
  "_method" => "PUT"
  "file" => "IMG_5626.jpg"
]
```

But if I try storing the file I get the following error:

```
Spatie\MediaLibrary\MediaCollections\Exceptions\FileDoesNotExist
File `IMG_5626.jpg` does not exist
```

This is making me crazy, seems everything is set up right. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd need to access the "files" part of your upload. Change

```
$request->input('image')
```

to

```
$request->file('image')
```

Answer (score 0):

#HomeController code should be like this#

```
public function updateProfileImage(Request $request){

$request->validate(
    [
        'image' => 'required',
    ]
);

$result = Auth::user()->addMedia($request->file('image'))->toMediaCollection('user-images');
```

return $result;

}